# Warning in java abstract generic method

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I have something like:

```
public abstract class Base{
    public abstact T <T> method();
}

public class ExtendingClass extends Base{
    public SomeObject method(){
    }
}
```

However, `ExtendingClass#method` has the warning **Type safety: The return type SomeObject for method from the type ExtendingClass needs unchecked conversion to conform to 
T from the type Base**

Can you please tell me why is this and how should this be handled?

Comment: Down-vote from me - your current code example is broken. The `Base` class doesn't compile. Note: I rolled back one edit that tried to fix this (but didn't) - only the OP should edit code in a question.

Comment: Does it need to if it's just showing an example of the problem?  He did say "something like"

Comment: @RossDrew I think so, yes. There is an entire close reason related to not providing code that demonstrates the specific problem. Now, this isn't the worst instance of that I've seen, but I expect a little bit of accuracy an effort from an OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
public abstract class Base<T> {
    public abstract T method();
}
```

and:

```
public class ExtendingClass extends Base<SomeObject >{

    public SomeObject method(){
        ...
    }

}
```

This happens because the generic parameters don't appear anywhere else except in your abstract method declaration.

This method signature is almost equivalent to `public abstract Object method()`.

From java [generic methods tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

> Generic methods allow type parameters to be used to express
>   dependencies among the types of one or more arguments to a method
>   and/or its return type. If there isn't such a dependency, a generic
>   method should not be used.

Comment: This doesn't explain why he gets the warning :)

Comment: I did try this thing and the warning is there. The purpose of not haveing 'Object' returned is more complicated, I need to keep 'T'.

Comment: Did you try making Base generic? can you add your generic Base code here?

Comment: yes, it works now - I think that my project remained 'unrefreshed' - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Base <T> {
    public abstract T method();
}



public class test extends Base<String>{

    @Override
    public String method(){
        return null;

    }
}
```

When you are writing the concrete example you must pass proper value for it so that compiler can verify the value during compilation

Comment: @kocko: I have already mentioned in my answer that 'compiler can verify the value during compilation'

Comment: I did try this thing and the warning is there. The purpose of not haveing 'Object' returned is more complicated, I need to keep 'T'.

Comment: @Roxana: Eclipse is not giving me any warning :(

Comment: yes, it works now - I think that my project remained 'unrefreshed' - thanks